# Heroku action caching doesn't seem to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, memcached, action-caching

I have been playing around with different caching strategies on Heroku and have add their memcached add-on with an aim to add action caching to my app.

When I view Rails.cache.stats on my current app however (with memcached installed and using the dalli gem) I get current and total_items at 0 after performing the actions that should be cached.

At the top of the controller with the action I want to cache I have:

```
caches_action :show
```

Also, I modified my environment config (for the one running on Heroku) to have

```
config.cache_store = :dalli_store
```

Is there some other stats I can look at to see if it is working or have I done something wrong?

Comment: `http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/memcache` you have gone through all of that and added the necessary configs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable caching as well as configuring a cache store:

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching             = true
```